# ag-grid API Undefined in Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am writing the unit test case for Ag-grid in angular.

**test.component.ts:**

```js
public gridApi: GridApi; 
public gridColumnApi;

constructor(private service: Service) {
 this.initializeAgGrid(); // this method just initializing the grid
}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.setHraDashboardData();
}

onGridReady(params) {
 this.gridApi = params.api;
 this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
 this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
}

setHraDashboardData() {
 this.service.getData(1).then((data) => {
   this.uiData = data;
   this.rowData = this.generateRowData(this.data); // this method writing some logic for UI
   this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
 });
}
```

**test.component.spec.ts**

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HraFormComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('grid API is available after `detectChanges`', async() => {
  await fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const elm = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const grid = elm.querySelector('#Grid');
    const firstRowCells = grid.querySelectorAll('div[row-id="0"] div.ag-cell-value');
    const values = Array.from(firstRowCells).map((cell: any) => cell.textContent.trim());

    // assert
    expect(component.rowData[0].title).toEqual(values[0]);
  });
});
```

Now above test case is getting failed to due to `component.gridApi` is `undefined`, so it's not able to assign value for the grid `this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData)`.

Comment: The question makes sense, I myself was struggling to get angular ag-grid based tests to work, since the answer looks to have helped to resolve the issue, I recommend to not closing the question because it helps to write unit test for components that use the ag-grid library. I've asked a specific question about this in github, but the link got removed, so here you have the way to get around this from the experience I'd when writing unit tests for ag-grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing unit tests that involves the availability of the ag-grid api, two things can help you in this case:

Instead of waiting for the `gridReady` event, you can try to use the `this.gridOptions.api` (this.gridOptions.api.setRowData ...) because most of the time, it is initialized sooner (before onGridReady firing)

You can do that in combination of using a [settimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) function as well, I used that multiple times when I got a similar issue as yours in the past:

instead of:

```js
this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
```

Try:

```js
setTimeout(() => { this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);}, 100);
```

You can increase the time for the [settimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to 200, 300, 500 or more, for me, most of the time just using the `settimeout` with a very small number (10 milliseconds) worked.

The [settimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is not an ideal solution but that works in many cases. The first options should be more clean, and you can even add a timeout as well to get it to work.

Use a [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) zone instead of the `async` one will help as well.